# Using UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app have subclass from UITabBarController, and this class not Root for window. After login in the system, I show this controller. After I touch on the button on view, I want push viewcontroller on the active tap, how can i do this?

Comment: Could you share the code which you have implemented.

Comment: Add UINavigationController to tap, and hide navigation bar. Then simple push new view controller when button pressed

Comment: or better add UINavigationController to the root, and select Push segue from the button to the UITabBarController.

Answer (score -1):

Add a `UINavigationController` and use it to push.That is the purpose of navigation controller